# AngularJS ng-repeat with radio inputs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of options as an enum:

```
var Options = {
    Option0: 0,
    Option1: 1,
    Option2: 2,
    Option3: 3,
    Option4: 4    
};
```

And a sub-list of available options:

```
var availabledOptions = [
  Options.Option0,
  Options.Option2,  
  Options.Option4  
];
```

I then try to show the list of available options as radio inputs but it doesn't work and I'm wondering why. $scope.selectedOption is not updated.

```
function main($scope) {

    $scope.availabledOptions = availabledOptions;

    $scope.selectedOption = Options.Option2;   

}
</script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="main">       
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="option in availabledOptions">
            <input name="options" type="radio" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-value="option">option #{{option}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    selected option: option #{{selectedOption}}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1xgsqL67/

I tried ng-repeat="option in availabledOptions track by $index" and also without the name attribute, but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

`ng-model="$parent.selectedOption"`

My understanding is that `ng-repeat` creates it's own scope, and you have to go up one level.

Comment: Or you could create set the model to an attribute of a different object in the scope like so: `$scope.selectedOption = {};` and  `ng-model="selectedOption.selected"`.